# Converting List to Binary Search Tree, and the opposite

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

Using:

```
data BST = MakeNode BST String BST
          |  Empty
```

My type declaration is

```
listToBST :: [String] -> BST
BSTToList :: BST -> [String]
```

Also, I'm trying to use folding and list comprehensions instead of standard recursion.
If someone could help me out it would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, the easist function I could come up is `listToBst _ = Empty`. Or do you have certain requirements of *hpw* this should be done? If so, it could help to tell us about.

Comment: it has to be a legal binary search tree. The elements added to the tree from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to use the `add` function from a previous question.

Then you can implement the functions like this:

```
listToBST :: [String] -> BST
listToBST = foldr add Empty

bstToList :: BST -> [String]
bstToList = flip go []
  where
    -- Uses a difference list for efficient appends
    go :: BST -> [String] -> [String]
    go Empty = id
    go (MakeNode l p r) = go l . (p:) . go r
```

Comment: for the listToBST, when I'm entering a list with the function it just prints all the strings diagonally down to the right.
Where it should take the first member in the list, and it's at the top, then the proceeding list elements fall down through the tree, left or right as a binary search tree does

Comment: removing elements from these trees looks like its the hardest to code.